# Swapping the text with the function

Tags: javascript, function, text

I am still a newbie with javascript and I wanted to know how to make it so that the function appears and the text next to that,

What I mean by that is, it is now show loading and next to it the variable text but I what I want is that the variable text is in front of the static 'loading' text

```
loader.text('Loading '+$(this).text()).show();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Super unclear what you're asking. What do you mean "in front"? Do you just want to *prepend* the text, instead of *appending* it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a good idea for you to check out some beginner Javascript resources. What you're trying to do is very basic, and is called "string concatenation". Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just reorder the text in the call.

```
loader.text($(this).text()+' loading').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct, furthermore..

jQuery's `.text()` returns the innerHtml string value of whatever element you are targeting.

```
$(this).text()
```

So lets say we have an element:

```
<div id="test">Hello World</div>
```

if we get the text value of this element..

```
$("#test").text();
```

it will surely return "Hello World", a string value.

In your Javascript, the `+` represents joining the strings "Loading" with "Hello World" with a result of "Loading Hello World". This is called concatenation.

so in order to rearrange how the text appears, just reorder how it is being concatenated, or put together.

```
loader.text(  $(this).text()  +  ' loading').show();
```

instead of

```
loader.text( 'Loading'   +   $(this).text()  ).show();
```